# how to access camera from another object in unity 3d

Tags: c#, object, camera, unity-game-engine, raycasting

My script is attached to a character controller.

And i declared,

```
public Camera camera;
```

in class. In update function i given,

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){ 
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit3, 400.0F)){
    print(hit3.collider.gameObject.name); 
}
}
```

But i am getting error

```
"UnassignedReferenceException: 
The variable camera of 'characterScript' has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the camera variable of the 
characterScript script in the inspector."
```

Help me with a good solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didnt initialize your camera. you have to set it through the UI of unity3D. Just drag and drop the camera to the public parametr.

Answer (score 3):

Drag and drop it to the variable in the UI, or add this bit in the script to do it automatically at startup:

```
void Start()
{ 
    camera = (Camera) GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(Camera));
}
```

The cast might be redundant.
Also, only works properly if you have exactly one camera.

Comment: This script wont works correctly if he have few cameras on the scene. So he should drag and drop the camera from UI, this will work on 100%

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote exactly that :)
But I agree, the best bet is to drag to variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can also access the camera(s) from anywhere by using the following static variables of the Camera class:

`Camera.current` The camera we are currently rendering with.

`Camera.main` The first enabled camera tagged "MainCamera".

`Camera.allCameras` Returns all enabled cameras in the scene.

No need to look for it, the Camera class takes care of keeping track of its instances for us :)

hth.

Jerome